# SwiftUI Is there any built in view that kind of slides in from the side and takes up 3/4 of the screen?

Tags: swiftui

This is probably a custom view but in the Reddit app there's a toolbar and the top left button(3 lines) opens this kind of view from the side that moves the current view to the right so you can only see about 25% of it and a new view that takes up about 75% of the screen slides in. Is there anything like this built into SwiftUI and if there isn't how would I go about implementing something like this?

Comment: look up `sidebar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my custom side bar behave similarly to what you just mentioned, you can try it. (Images and Code are below)

Before click:

[image]

After clicked:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var isClicked = false
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.orange)
            .frame(width: isClicked ? UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.75 : 0)
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    withAnimation {
                        isClicked.toggle()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "menucard.fill")
                        .padding(.leading)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
  }
}
```